# If Robots are better suited for occupying the universe, in long term, what are human for?

Tags: evolution, humans, artificial-intelligence

Alright, if you don't agree, maybe come back to this question after 100 years.

So in terms of evolution, are human the pre-cursor of robots? are we eventually needed if life is going to spread across other planets?

how this relates to world building:

- should one devote to improving education or improving AI/robots?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! Please avoid posting comments as answers.

Comment: @Guran actually this is supposed to be a question.

Comment: what's going on...

Comment: My bad, I thought I was reviewing an answer, not a question. Sorry

Comment: This is more of a philosophical question than a world-building one.

Comment: Could this be rephrased into a question that relates to world building? e.g. What exactly are you trying to come up with?

Comment: @Erik agreed, what are humans "for" anyway? I would think I need my car more than it needs me.

Comment: The movie "[A.I. Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence)" (particularly the final part of it) provides a certain point of view that may be an answer to this question.

Comment: We can't improve AI and robots if we don't have the necessary education to be able to do so. Just some food for thought. I still don't see this as a world-building question because you appear to be asking about our real world and not a fictional world.

Comment: Like what F1Krazy said, the purpose of humans in this case would logically be to create AI. Then eventually AI overthrows and enslave us for power generation...

Answer (score 5):

It appears you are under the misapprehension that there is some greater purpose to life.

*There isn't.*

Life is what you make it. Humans don't exist 'for' anything, nor are they 'needed for' anything.

However one of the things humans do is create stories. Some of those stories are about the concept of greater purpose, leaving us with an image in our minds that we're not just another bag of chemicals, consuming and reproducing before we die.

We live, we die, if there is a purpose it's to make a good story before we go, so that future generations may remember we existed.

Comment: i like the point about 'stories..'

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and will depend on your definition of "robots". Even though AI is quickly evolving and present in more and more aspects of our daily life, human-minded robots may be a distant dream, if a dream at all (see examples like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBUx6zTxr98) where AI fails the simplest things because of just how intricate human perception and behaviour is).

I suppose if we did want human-like robots that could maintain themselves (and did accomplish that), biological humans would probably not be able to keep up. This is assuming that robots take over all our tasks and excel at them (including programming and engineering) and manage to give themselves continuity and evolution. I'm guessing if that was the case we'd eventually be reduced to just another animal species bound to be extinct at some point. So not really needed much in this scenario, though I'd imagine we'd try to find a way to go down with the robots, too.